# Unable to figure out the usage of AudioQueueDispose in Swift

Tags: swift, audioqueue

I'm sure this is something stupid I'm doing wrong but why is the swift parser telling me I can't convert the expression's type () when clearly the definition of AudioQueueDispose returns an OSStatus type? I've put off asking this question for a while cos I know it's going to be something dumb I'm just overlooked.

I put this in to Xcode playground for simplicity...

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox
import AVFoundation

var audioQueue:AudioQueue
var status : OSStatus = OSStatus(noErr)
status = AudioQueueDispose(audioQueue, inImmediate: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message was very misleading especially with the little arrow pointing to the '=' sign implying it was an issue with the return type. Anyway, the actual problem is to do with using 'false', which is a swift type 'Bool', whereas the function expects at type 'Boolean' which is in fact a UInt8. So the above can be fixed by writing...

```
status = AudioQueueDispose(audioQueue, 0)
```

Perhaps someone can offer a better solution which does not involve using integers?

For now I'm just defining a couple of constants..

```
let FALSE:Boolean = 0
let TRUE:Boolean = 1
```